# Domain name resolves to IP address in browser address bar

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ip

I have a site that I'm hosting on my home server, and I'm using a no-ip domain name. Port 80 is in use by another application on the network I'm using, so I set the no-ip account as a port 80 redirect, and I'm using port 81. I'm now able to access my site, but when I navigate to the site, it resolves to the IP:port number in the address bar. Any pointers on where to check would be appreciated, I've checked the apache2.conf file, as well as ports.conf, and the corresponding configuration file in sites-enabled. Please advise if any further information is needed.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html read this document. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is 'redirect'. When you visit `http://domainname/`, you reach a website that explicitly redirects your browser elsewhere, by sending a HTTP [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) header like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Look elsewhere
Location: http://ipaddress:port/blah.html
```

It might be the no-ip service doing this, or it might be misconfiguration in your own website or webserver. Can't give a better answer without knowing the *real* domain name and being able to look at it.

Comment: My domain name is [sirknight.no-ip.biz](http://sirknight.no-ip.biz), if you want to take a look. Would I need to use a packet sniffing tool, such as wireshark, in order to see the header you specified?

Comment: @Glenak1911: Yes, or the web browser's [network inspector](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DxW7m.png) (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+K or such). Also, note that DNS _does not_ handle :ports (at least for the web), so if you want people to type `http://sirknight.no-ip.biz` and connect to port 81, you _will_ need a redirect that reveals the :port (e.g. `Location: http://sirknight.no-ip.biz:81/`).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an option on the no-ip settings to mask the url with a frameset. I started doing some research into how to mask URLs, and found the following useful page:

http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/url-masking.php